# Is $MonCat$ locally presentable?

Tags: category-theory, limits-colimits, monoidal-categories, locally-presentable-categories

Is the category of monoidal categories and strict monoidal functors locally presentable?

Recall this means that there is a small set of small objects $S$ such that any object in $MonCat$ can be obtained as a colimit over a diagram with objects in $S$.